# Getting Paypal Payment State as "DEAD"

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am getting below give response while doing PayPal payment with card using sandbox credentials.

```
{
    "client": {
        "environment": "sandbox",
        "paypal_sdk_version": "2.14.6",
        "platform": "Android",
        "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK"
    },
    "response": {
        "create_time": "2017-01-31T08:12:40Z",
        "id": "PAY-*************",
        "intent": "sale",
        "state": "created"
    },
    "response_type": "payment"
}
```

Then i tried to get Full details by Payment ID using rest API call and getting "DEAD" state on payment response. Please check below response

```
{
  "id": "PAY-*************",
  "create_time": "2017-01-31T08:12:40Z",
  "update_time": "2017-01-31T08:13:22Z",
  "state": "DEAD",
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [
      {
        "credit_card": {
          "type": "visa",
          "number": "xxxxxxxxxxxx1111",
          "expire_month": "11",
          "expire_year": "2025"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "2.00",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "2.00"
        }
      },
      "description": "New Product",
      "related_resources": []
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-*************",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone please help me to understand why i am getting this ? how to fix this ?

Comment: Hey! How did you fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got the solution. It's a bit late to reply here but this answer can save time for those who are still struggling.

The JSON below is returned by Android SDK after creating a payment but we can see its status is not approved yet. If we use the payment lookup API (`https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-*************`) to verify the payment we will get a DEAD status and there will not be any transaction id.

```
{
    "client": {
        "environment": "sandbox",
        "paypal_sdk_version": "2.14.6",
        "platform": "Android",
        "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK"
    },
    "response": {
        "create_time": "2017-01-31T08:12:40Z",
        "id": "PAY-*************",
        "intent": "sale",
        "state": "created"
    },
    "response_type": "payment"
}
```

**Solution that worked for me**

The problem was I created a Business account in my sandbox, but I had to create a **Business-Pro** account in sandbox. After doing this I got the approved status and when I use the payment lookup API, I get all details we need.